# PHP MVC different stylesheets, javascript files on every page

Tags: php, css

each one of my pages shares the common.css stylesheet but then nearly every other page has its own custom stylesheet and this is the same for javascript files.

My main template file is in this sort of format (obviously the real one has more html in it):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo $this->data['title']; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php echo $this->data['content']; ?>
</body>
```

I was thinking of doing it this way:

When I create the view object in the controller I could add the required files (in an array) to the view object so then they could be accessed in the main template like `$this->data['css']` and `$this->data['javascript']` and I could loop through the arrays in the main template to output them in the `<head>` of the page.

Is this an okay way to do it or is it breaking some rules or bad practice? Thanks.

Comment: If you include the entire CSS in one external file, it will likely be cached by the user, which might end up in better performance for them.

Comment: Wouldn't that would be a disaster to maintain and edit though? Is that what most sites are doing these days?

Comment: I don't think so, you set up your CSS in one file and have your output use the elements within it. Might take some effort to set up at first (as in working out all the styles you will need) but once set up will be *much* easier than sending inline CSS with each function. What happens if you want to update your site style - do you really want to dig through potentially thousands of lines of code for each style tag?

Comment: I don't use any inline CSS though. All my pages share a common.css file with styling for the header, footer etc but then each page has other stylesheets. For example the register page has a seperate stylesheet (register.css) because it has different stuff on the page compared to the privacy policy page etc. It also has a form.css (has the css for my custom input text fields and form related elements). If i put all my css into one file it would be 1000s and 1000s of lines of css in one file and I don't think that would work it would drive me mad if I had to edit a piece of it.

Answer (score 0):

It is totally okay, though I advice you to write yourself a `asset()` method in order to prepend your basepath before filename [e.g. `http://yoursite.com/web/`] so your code is more portable an deploying is easier.

As Fluffeh said consider compressing your whole styles in a single file for better performance - check [YUI compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) for example.

Comment: What do you mean by write yourself an asset()? Write an asset function that does what exactly or write an asset class?

Comment: Sorry, I meant an `asset()` method of your class, so you can call `$this -> asset('style.css')` or the whole array, as you wish.

Comment: Ok that gave me the idea of maybe writing a little class which manages external files (css and javascript) and I can implement that into my view maybe.